# Datatables.net fnGetPosition returns -1 for iColumnIndex when adding a new row and then clicking on the row 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am getting my position using:

```
this.fnGetPosition = function( nNode )
    {
        var oSettings = _fnSettingsFromNode( this[DataTable.ext.iApiIndex] );
        var sNodeName = nNode.nodeName.toUpperCase();

        if ( sNodeName == "TR" )
        {
            return _fnNodeToDataIndex(oSettings, nNode);
        }
        else if ( sNodeName == "TD" || sNodeName == "TH" )
        {
            var iDataIndex = _fnNodeToDataIndex( oSettings, nNode.parentNode );
            var iColumnIndex = _fnNodeToColumnIndex( oSettings, iDataIndex, nNode );
            return [ iDataIndex, _fnColumnIndexToVisible(oSettings, iColumnIndex ), iColumnIndex ];
        }
        return null;
    };
```

If I click into row 0, iDataIndex contains 0 and iColumnIndex contains whatever column I clicked in.  But if I add a new row, lets say row 9 and then I click into row 0, iDataIndex still holds 9 instead of 0 and iColumnIndex returns -1.  I have to turn bServerSide off when adding a new row because if I don't, clicking the add new row button will not add a blank row, but make an ajax call.  Once I add the row, I turn bServerSide back on.

`fnNodeToDataIndex` looks like this:

```
function _fnNodeToDataIndex( oSettings, n )
    {
        return (n._DT_RowIndex!==undefined) ? n._DT_RowIndex : null;
    }
```

`fnNodeToColumnIndex` looks like this:

```
function _fnNodeToColumnIndex( oSettings, iRow, n )
    {
        var anCells = _fnGetTdNodes( oSettings, iRow );

        for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aoColumns.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
        {
            if ( anCells[i] === n )
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

This is the function that gets called when I want to add the new row:

```
/* Add single row and display */
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnAddDataAndDisplay = function(oSettings, aData) {
/* Add the data */
var iAdded = this.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, aData);
var nAdded = oSettings.aoData[iAdded].nTr;

/* Need to re-filter and re-sort the table to get positioning correct, not perfect
* as this will actually redraw the table on screen, but the update should be so fast (and
* possibly not alter what is already on display) that the user will not notice
*/
this.oApi._fnReDraw(oSettings);

/* Find it's position in the table */
var iPos = iAdded;

/* Get starting point, taking account of paging */
if (iPos >= 0) {
    oSettings._iDisplayStart = (Math.floor(iPos / oSettings._iDisplayLength)) * oSettings._iDisplayLength;
    this.oApi._fnCalculateEnd(oSettings);
}

this.oApi._fnDraw(oSettings);
return {
    "nTr": nAdded,
    "iPos": iAdded
};
```

};

Comment: I suppose a fiddle is out of the question?